# refresh post user without refresh page ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i don't know , not working !

-i have table post for user

- i want display post without refresh page used ajax

  ```
   <form class="posting" method="POST" autocomplete="off" 
     action="createpost.php">      

          <textarea name="text" class="textarea" ></textarea>

  <button class="btn-ajouter" type="submit" name="ajouter" value="ajouter">ajouter</button>                           
  </form>
  ```

// code mysql the same page

```
 <?php 

       $stmt = $connect->query('SELECT post FROM publications
                                  ORDER BY date_post DESC ');

      while($row=$stmt->fetch() )
      {
 ?>
           <div class="allpost"> 

 <?php 
          echo $row['post'].'<br>' ;
  ?>
           </div>

 <?php 
   }
   ?>
```

(jquery exist in page index )  (  )

```
  <script>
  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'createpost.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

- but not working

Comment: edited sorry  
$('form').on('submit'

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: "not working" is not very helpful... what does it do? do you get an error? on screen? in the developer tools console?

Comment: not error console and nothing function , just i  want when user post display post  without refresh page

Comment: Not even an alert pops up?

Comment: Just to confirm. Have you included jquery.js file? :P

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that you are trying to display the information on the same page where the user submits the form. I would advise you to put the php code in a **separate file** and then print it somewhere on the page with javascript. A sample code for that would be something like this:

*Javascript code on your current page*

```
<script>
  $(function () {

   // I actually agree with Lawrence Cherone's suggestions here, so i'm including them
   $('form.posting').on('submit', function (e) {

      form_data = $(this).serialize()
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'separate.php',
        data: form_data,
        success: function (response) {
          //then you can have the server output as an object
          response = JSON.parse(response);
          //And print it somewhere, for example:
          $('#someDiv').html(response.whatever);
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

*Code for php in a separate file*

```
<?php 

  $stmt = $connect->query('SELECT post FROM publications
                                      ORDER BY date_post DESC ');
  $row = $stmt->fetch();

  echo json_encode($row['post']);
```

Comment: The `<button type="submit"` inside the `form` already triggers the `submit` event on click.

Comment: Hmm. That's right. He edited his question on the meantime.

Comment: The OPs code is fine, no need to switch to `$('body').on('click','.btn-ajouter'`, instead the OP should narrow down the selector for example `$('form.posting').on('submit',`, remove `$('form').serialize(),` and grab it from `var form_data = $(this).serialize()` outside the ajax object. Your also using `$('#somewere').html(response);` but now returing json.. wtf.

Comment: what #somewere ?

Comment: The OP changed his question, so I'm still editing my response, no need to rush dude ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change this button. Since you want to run an AJAX call It shouldn't be a SUBMIT.

```
<button class="btn-ajouter" type="submit" name="ajouter" value="ajouter">ajouter</button>
```

to this

```
<button class="btn-ajouter" id="ajouter" name="ajouter" value="ajouter">ajouter</button>
```

and change your JQuery from

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
```

to

```
$('#ajouter').on('click', function (e) {
```

Also, you won't need to e.preventDefault();

Comment: "_Since you want to run an AJAX call It shouldn't be a SUBMIT_" Why ?

Comment: Why would you want to trigger a form submit and then cancel if if you are making an AJAX call?

Comment: Yeah and retracted once you fixed the issue, thats how SO works. It works both ways, if you didn't edit I wouldn't be able to retract ;p

Comment: @GordonKushner Your question could be asked for form validation too. There is an event for, just use it. Otherwise, why would you even use a form ?

Comment: @SergeK fair enough. As company best-practice, we don't use forms at all for AJAX-only pages. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Change this form,

```
 <form class="posting" method="POST" autocomplete="off" onSubmit="return false">      

    <textarea name="text" id="text" class="textarea" ></textarea>

<button class="btn-ajouter" type="submit" id="ajouter" name="ajouter" value="ajouter">ajouter</button>                           
</form>
```

**Ajax Goes Here,**

```
    $(function(){
    $("#ajouter").click(function(){
var text=$("#text").val();
$.ajax({
url:"createpost.php",
method:"POST",
data:{text:text},
cache:false,
success:function(data){
$("#result").load(location.href+ "#result");
}
  });
    });
    });
```

PHP & HTML Code goes here

```
<div id="result">
 <?php 

   $stmt = $connect->query('SELECT post FROM publications
                              ORDER BY date_post DESC ');

  while($row=$stmt->fetch() )
  {
 ?>
           <div class="allpost"> 

 <?php 
          echo $row['post'].'<br>' ;
  ?>
           </div>

 <?php 
   }
   ?>

</div>
```

Comment: $("#result").load(location.href+ "#result");